# Spring Cloud Eureka Server + Custom Auto-Configured Web Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am having an issue with the filter order when using a custom auto-configured web security configuration **from a different project** together with Spring Cloud Eureka Server. When using the custom auto-configured web security config, the `springSecurityFilterChain` appears after the `servletContainer` filter that is created by the `EurekaServerConfiguration`. Hence, access to the Eureka dashboard is secured but `/eureka/*` do not have the Spring Security filter chain applied.

If I use the default Spring Boot auto-configured Web Security (i.e `security.basic.*` properties, the filter order is correct.

If I use a create a custom web security configuration in the **same project** and a **different configuration class** as the Discovery Server, the filter order is correct. If I annotate the main application class with `@EnableWebSecurity` or add a static inner class within the main application class with `@EnableWebSecurity` I also get the incorrect filter order.

What am I incorrectly providing the auto-configuration or missing something in the implementation details of the web security configuration?

A repository with full examples: [Eureka Security Config Examples](https://github.com/steve-oakey/eureka-security-example)

**Setup**

#### module - my-autoconfiguration

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass(EnableWebSecurity.class)
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
           auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }
    }
}
```

This project contains a META-INF folder with a `spring.factories` file
and the appropriate class added under the `EnableAutoConfiguration` key. I have verified via `-Ddebug` that the class is a positive match.

#### module - discovery-server

I include the above module as a dependency as well as `spring-boot-starter-security`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Filter Order - Expected (when using Spring Boot basic security or custom security within discovery-server project)

```
Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'webRequestTraceFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

#### Filter Order - Result (custom auto-configured web security)

```
Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'webRequestTraceFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is when you use the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation, it disables the automatic configuration of security provided by Spring Boot in `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security).

When using `@EnableWebSecurity`, the `springSecurityFilterChain` bean is instantiated in `WebSecurityConfiguration`. Since this bean is a plain `Filter`, it does not have an `Order`. When using the automatic configuration provided by `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration`, the `springSecurityFilterChain` bean is wrapped in a `FilterRegistrationBean` with an order that you can specify in your configuration files or a default of `0` (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640 for more details).

When using Spring Boot, it tries to fetch the order of the `Filter` before wiring them into the container. When using `@EnableWebSecurity`, since `springSecurityFilterChain` bean has no order, it will get a default value of `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` in the class `OrderComparator`. This is the same value of the `jersey` bean defined in `EurekaServerConfiguration` who is responsible for the calls made to the `/eureka` prefix. In the bootstrap phase of Eureka, the `jersey` bean is instantiated before the unordered `springSecurityFilterChain` and will get wired before in the filter chain, hence disabling the security on the `/eureka` prefix.

To fix the problem, simply add a `FilterRegistrationBean` wrapping the `springSecurityChain` bean in your Configuration class annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity` :

```
    @Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(name = AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME)
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChainRegistration(@Qualifier(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME) Filter securityFilter)
{
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);
    registration.setOrder(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER);
    registration.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    return registration;
}
```

I've put the default order of `0` here, you could make it configurable like they do in the `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration`. This will make the `springSecurityChain` bean as if it was autoconfigured.